# Generate a PDF of a Stripe Draft Invoice

Tags: stripe-payments

In Stripe, once you finalize an invoice, [its status](https://stripe.com/docs/invoicing/overview#invoice-statuses) is updated from `draft` to `open`. Then you can both download a PDF of it or view a hosted page of it.

Can you download a PDF of a draft invoice? I could not find a way to do this in either the API or the Dashboard.

Both the `invoice_pdf` and `hosted_invoice_url` fields are null until finalizing the invoice. To me, it makes sense why only open invoices get a hosted page, but it feels strange that there is no way to download a PDF of a draft invoice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to create a PDF of a draft Invoice in Stripe.

It sounds like you may want to use [Quotes](https://stripe.com/docs/quotes) instead:

> Quotes enable you to combine recurring and one-off line items so you can provide your customers with a price estimate, including any discounts or taxes. ​​Stripe enables you to convert the quote into a recurring subscription or a one-time invoice after the customer accepts the quote.

Quotes also need to be finalized before you can [download a PDF](https://stripe.com/docs/api/quotes/pdf), but Quotes aren't actual Invoices or Subscriptions until you [accept them](https://stripe.com/docs/api/quotes/accept), so finalizing them has very few consequences.  You can even [clone a new Quote from an existing Quote using `from_quote`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/quotes/create#create_quote-from_quote).

Comment: This is what I've concluded too. Quotes are probably what I should use, but we are still on the basic plan. If we upgrade to Stripes Invoicing Plus or Billing Scale plans they're what I will use. It would still be nice to be able to download a PDF of a draft Quote though!